# AddClass doesn't applied properly in my case

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use addClass to add .saved, and the class got added

```
.saved{
    text-align: left !important;
    background: #000 url('http://i.imgur.com/M9cySTa.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px;
    background-position: 87% 8px;
    padding-left: 16px !important;
}
```

strange thing is the background property is not working. Take a look on my demo here http://jsfiddle.net/k87zp2gj/ Supposedly the img will come out after .saved is added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the selector have a higher precedence so that its rules override any previously set on that element:

```
.btn.saved {
    text-align: left !important;
    background: #000 url('http://i.imgur.com/M9cySTa.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px;
    background-position: 87% 8px;
    padding-left: 16px !important;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k87zp2gj/2/)

The alternative is to use `!important` on the `background` property, however this is bad practice as it then makes overriding that property at a later date much harder. Only use `!important` when there is no other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Because `.btn` `.btn-dark` are overriding the style of `.saved`

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k87zp2gj/2/)